# MATLAB logm error

Tags: matrix, matlab

By the BCH formula (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula), if I take X and Y as two antisymmetric matrices, then using matlab notation, I should get logm(expm(X)*expm(Y)) as antisymmetric since the linear terms are antisymmetric by definition and the commutators are antisymmetric. Now the problem is as follows:-

```
x = rand(5);
y = rand(5);
x = x-x';
y = y-y';
xy = logm(expm(100*1i*x)*expm(1i*y))
```

We can see that MATLAB result for xy is not antisymmetric but if I replace the factor 100 in the formula by a smaller number such as ranging from 1 to 15, the antisymmetric nature is still retained. How can I correct this error ? Please feel free to ask questions if needed.

Comment: Are you sure you are not overflowing when computing the matrix exponential?

Comment: vsoftco : yes, I guess that might be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code in `Mathematica`, which deals with large numbers much better than MATLAB. You are overloading, i.e. components of `expm(100*1i*x)` are of the order `10^50`. Also, even for smaller constants, like `20`, the smallest eigenvalue of `expm(100*1i*x)*expm(1i*y)` becomes very small compared to the other, which makes the matrix logarithm quite imprecise.

Comment: Hi vsoftco, is Mathematica able to deal with larger(>20) constants in the expression ?

Comment: Not really, since it believes an eigenvalue is zero when trying to compute the matrix logarithm. Whenever it works you get what you expect, an anti-symmetric matrix. But you can rescale the matrices, like `x=x/1000` and `y=y/1000`, and you won't overflow anymore.

Comment: vsoftco : will using arbitrary precision not help ? I cannot rescale the matrices in the way you mentioned as my system is not linear and it is not possible to keep track of the effect of scaling.

Comment: @user56199 I am not sure about arbitrary precision, and I don't know how to use it in MATLAB. I find it a bit strange that you cannot rescale, cannot you use somehow the fact that exp(cA)=[exp(A)]^c (this is true for matrices also)?

Comment: vsoftco : As an example, I am unable to know how the scaling of matrices M1, M2 and M3 will change the quantity log(trace(exp(M1)*exp(M2)*exp(M3))) since ([exp(M1)]^c)*([exp(M2)]^c)*([exp(M3)]^c) is not same as [exp(M1)*exp(M2)*exp(M3)]^c since they are non-commuting

Comment: @user56199 yes it doesn't seem trivial... the non-commutativity is what makes it hard indeed. The only thing that comes to my mind is to use directly the series expansion in BCH formula and compute it term by term (you have alternating signs so you may not overflow). I am not sure this is what you are after though...